# How to check if a variable is empty in tcl

Tags: tcl

How do you ceck if a variable is empty ? It could contain a `"\n"` or spaces. 
I am currently doing this

```
if {{string trimleft $var} != ""} {
   # the variable is not empty
   puts $var
 }
```

However the variable printed still seems to be empty ?  will `trimleft` remove `"\n"` ?
Is there a  better approach to check if a string is empty ?

Comment: You wrote `{string trimleft $var}`, but you probably should have written `[string trimleft $var]`. The difference in brackets is fundamental to Tcl; curlies are quotes, squares are script substitutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if {{string trimleft "\n"} eq ""} {
    puts "1"
} elseif {"\n" eq ""} {
    puts "2"
}
```

- The above script will give output as nothing.
- I think `trimleft` won't remove `\n` from the value.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27453094/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-empty-in-tcl#comment43350996_27453094. `trimleft` _will_ remove `\n`, but you've got to use square brackets so that `string trimleft` actually gets called.

Answer (score 9):

As far as I know, checking if a string is empty is simply done by:

```
if {$myString eq ""} {

    puts "string is empty"

}
```

Running the following should not print anything:

```
if {" " eq ""} {
    puts "1"
} elseif {"\n" eq ""} {
    puts "2"
}
```

I hope I understood your question correctly

Answer (score 5):

To answer the original question with a concern of checking for an empty line here is the corrected code example:

```
if {[string trim $var] != ""} {
    puts $var
}
```

Without specifying the ?chars? the trim will remove white space chars which are considered to be space, tab, newline and carriage return.